# Implementation of a Nested Interface of a Subclass

Tags: java, class, subclass, implements

In Java, can a class implement an interface nested in one of its sub-classes?

Comment: Could you provide an example of what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thilo, it is not the sub-class that is implementing the interface; it is the super-class that is implementing the interface and the interface is in the sub-class.

Comment: Are you asking if the superclass can already provide the implementation, so that the sub-class can just use it when it declares interface compliance? If so, yes.

Comment: " it is not the sub-class that is implementing the interface". Well, all subclasses inherit the interfaces from the superclass. So they cannot avoid also implementing it.

Comment: Ok, so a sub-class has an interface. My question is can the sub-class's super-class implement that interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the compiler will find a cyclic inheritance. Just try it:

```
class C implements B.A {} 

class B extends C {
   interface A {}
} 
// won't compile
```